# Utilizar uma variavel vinda do php em um arquivo js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou com o seguinte problema tenho uma variavel que contem o caminho de uma imagem no banco de dados preciso enviar esta variavel com o caminho para um arquivo js, mas até achei vários scripts com exemplos de como trazer esta variavel o problema é como vou utilizar ela em uma função, segue trecho do codigo:

> Arquivo crop.php

```
<?php
$sQuery=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM feridas WHERE ferida_id = $id_ferida");
$row_s = mysql_fetch_object($sQuery);
$img_caminho = "../" . $row_s->ferida_path;
$img_destino = "upload/" . $id_ferida . ".png";
$_SESSION["img_ferida"] = $row_s->ferida_path;
?>
<script type="text/javascript"> var param = "<?php echo $img_destino ?>";> </script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='../include/cropmaster/crop.js'> </script>
```

> Arquivo crop.js:

```
//Funçao que traz a variavel php
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var pagina = param;
jQuery('#btnpaginas').click(function(){
    pagina++;
    var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "crop.php?pagina="+pagina,
        data: dados,
        success: function(data)
        {
            $(".paginacao").html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

```
//funçao para fazer um crop na imagem
$(document).ready(function() {
var condition = 1;
var points = [];//holds the mousedown points
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
this.isOldIE = (window.G_vmlCanvasManager);
$(function() {
  //  if (document.domain == 'localhost') {

        if (this.isOldIE) {
            G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(myCanvas);
        }
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var imageObj = new Image();
        function init() {
            canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
        }
        // Draw  image onto the canvas
        imageObj.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
        };
        imageObj.src = "dados";
```

//imageObj.src = recebe variavel que vem do php

Comment: Esse código JavaScript é todo o conteúdo do arquivo **crop.js** ou são arquivos diferentes ? Porque você está usando três vezes **(document).ready**, e no arquivo **crop.php** só tem esse HTML de retorno? O retorno não poderia ser no formato JSON? Pois da a entender que o arquivo **crop.js** já foi importado no documento.

Comment: O arquivo .js realmente foi importado para o PHP, mas preciso jogar uma variável do PHP dentro dele. Que contém um caminho de uma imagem que vem do banco de dados o Js não ler a variável PHP, por se tratar de linguagens diferentes lado servidor e outra lado cliente, utilizei o Ajax mas não conseguir êxito com a variável.

Comment: salva em um input hidden é a imagem destino né? faça assim no php <input id="imagemdest" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $imagem_destino; ?>" /> e pegue com o javascript var imagejavascript = document.getElementById('imagemdest').value;

Comment: Ok, Muito Obrigado irei testar essa alterantiva.